# How to Create random key in secure enclave in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, cryptography, private-key

I'm trying to create an RSA key for signing data in my Xamarin.iOS app on a physical device. Below is my code

```
using (var access = new SecAccessControl(SecAccessible.WhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly, SecAccessControlCreateFlags.BiometryCurrentSet|SecAccessControlCreateFlags.PrivateKeyUsage))
            {
                var keyParameters = new SecKeyGenerationParameters
                {
                    KeyType = SecKeyType.RSA,
                    KeySizeInBits = 2048,
                    Label = AppInfo.PackageName,
                    TokenID = SecTokenID.SecureEnclave,
                    PrivateKeyAttrs = new SecKeyParameters
                    {
                        IsPermanent = true,
                        ApplicationTag = NSData.FromString(AppInfo.PackageName, NSStringEncoding.UTF8),
                        AccessControl = access,
                        CanSign = true,
                        CanVerify = true
                    }
                };
                var privateKey = SecKey.CreateRandomKey(keyParameters.Dictionary, out NSError nsError);
                var publicKey = privateKey.GetPublicKey();
                NSData keyData = publicKey.GetExternalRepresentation();
            }
```

the above code is giving below  NSError and null private key

> {The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50 - Key generation failed, error -50)}.

The above code is working fine without *SecAccessControlCreateFlags.PrivateKeyUsage* and *TokenID = SecTokenID.SecureEnclave*

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Secure Enclave does not support RSA keys. It can only create elliptic curve keys with curve P256 (aka NIST P-256 or secp256r1). If you want to use RSA, you're left with the default Security implementation (without the Secure Enclave flag).

If you insist on using the secure enclave, you'll have to use the above mentioned curve.